# Dev Environment creation from Prod for Azure SQL

Tags: sql, azure

I have a production server in Azure SQL. I have created a another empty server(dev) for development purpose. I need a copy of the tables, views, stored procedure in the dev server as well. Please suggest some way to transfer the data to dev server database

Answer (score 1):

@John11 : You can take a backup of your Production Database and then simply restore on your Dev server

Ideally Production data restore to Dev is not advisable if it is a highly confidential data

If you just need to move the schema without data then you can use DevOps / CI-CD to deploy the artifacts to Dev